# Ubuntu 14.04 + pyes 0.99.2 + Elasticsearch 1.2.1

Tags: 14.04, python-2.7, django

Im using `Ubuntu 14.04` in a `Django Project` with `ElasticSearch` and after I install `pyes` with `pip install pyes==0.99.2` and try to acces to the ElasticSearch page, it returns an error from the OS:

`'module' object has no attribute 'PY2'` This is the Django error, but I'm pretty sure the problem cames from a lack of software or something related with the OS.

Does anyone has a similar issue using pyes 0.99.2 ? I've read looking for another packaged I needed to install or any action I need to do after the installation and  didn't find any usefull information

**edit**

Im using haystack 2.0.0

Comment: Why do you not simply use haystack as an interface to ES?

Comment: Sorry, I for got to say that im using haystack 2.0.0

Comment: Can you run `pip install six`?

Comment: I've already installed that package, but thanks for your help